# Loopback unable to insert record into a related model through lbServices functions

Tags: angularjs, node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

I'm building an application using loopback as backend and angularjs as frontend with MySql as database choice.
Loopback version is 2.22.0, Loopback angular sdk version is 1.5.0

There are models Person and Post. Both have auto generated "id" fields by loopback (i.e. `"idInjection": true`).

They both are related as `Person` hasMany `Post` and `Post` belongsTo `Person` linked by a foreign key on `personId` column in `Post` model.

Suppose there are already some records in both the tables.

I generated lbServices.js file by using lb-ng command. 
So now when I try to use the function

```
Person.posts.create({               
content: "Some content",
id: $rootScope.currentUser.id
})
```

it gives me error of duplicate entry.

I investigated this and found out that it's because the rest api url `"/People/:id/posts"` in lbServices.js file has an id parameter and also the Post model has an id column too which is a primary key.
So it passes id into both of them and fails. An ambiguity is formed.

For this example, `$rootScope.currentUser.id=1` and there already exists a row in `Post` table with `id=1`

Now when I change the `Post` model's property (`"idInjection": false`) and create a custom primary key column as "uid" with auto_increment.
I'm able to insert with

```
Person.posts.create({               
content: "Some content",
id: $rootScope.currentUser.id
})
```

So I want to know if I am inserting into a related model in the correct way or is this some issue with loopback? Or is there a better way to insert from AngularJs frontend?

I really want to avoid to change the primary column names of every model to something other than "id".

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out what I was doing wrong.
The correct way to insert should be:

```
Person.posts.create(
{id: $rootScope.currentUser.id},
{
   content: "Some content",
   title:   "Some title"
})
```

Answer (score 0):

As the id field is an autogenerated number, your call should be:

```
Person.posts.create({               
    content: "Some content",
    personId: $rootScope.currentUser.id
})
```

Comment: I tried this and got this error:

`POST http://localhost:3000/api/People/posts 404 (Not Found)`